# problems with ruby symbols in hash look-up

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, symbols

I'm trying to create a simple hash to look up for corresponding strings to some symbols (:student_number, :first_name, ...). I'm having issue retrieving data from this function though. Here's the function

Snippet A

```
  def get_nice_column_name(col_symbol)
    column_names = { 
      :first_name => "Student's First Name",
      :last_name => "Student's Last Name", 
      :email => "Student's Email", 
      :given_name => "Student's Given Name"
    }
    return column_names[col_symbol]
  end
```

Here's how I use it, but **not working**:

Snippet B

```
col_titles = []
params = {:first_name => 'true', 
          :last_name => 'true', 
          :email => 'true', 
          :given_name => 'true' }

params.each do |key, value|
  if ( value == 'true')
    col_titles << get_nice_column_name(key)
  end
end
```

When I look into col_titles, I expect ["Student's First Name", "Student's Last Name"], but I actually don't get anything, just [] empty array.

I thought that was weird so I tried printing out the object_id of the symbols (col_symbol in snippet A) and the symbols in the hash column_names, I get different object_ids. I'm wondering why they are different (they both present the same symbols). If I add this to the function get_nice_column_name in Snippet A:

```
    puts "col_symbol is " + col_symbol.object_id.to_s + ", while :first_name is " + (:first_name).object_id.to_s
    puts "col_symbol is " + col_symbol.object_id.to_s + ", while :last_name is " + (:last_name).object_id.to_s
    puts "col_symbol is " + col_symbol.object_id.to_s + ", while :email is " + (:email).object_id.to_s
    puts "col_symbol is " + col_symbol.object_id.to_s + ", while :given_name is " + (:given_name).object_id.to_s
```

I would get this in the console

```
col_symbol is 98351040, while :first_name is 1221688
col_symbol is 98351040, while :last_name is 580888
col_symbol is 98351040, while :email is 168888
col_symbol is 98351040, while :given_name is 1290648
```

983541040 doesn't really match any of the {1221688, 580888, 168888, 1290648}. Is this why my get_nice_column_name is useless ? Because the symbols are different under the hood?

Thanks for your help guys !

Regards

Comment: I just ran _exactly_ what you listed above, and it worked as per your expected behaviour. Is this the exact code you're having problems with?

Comment: Wow guys, thanks for the responses. After pulling an all nighter last night, I might have mixed things up. I found where the problem is now, the "params" array is actually what's passed back from a "form_tag", so , yes, it wasn't :first_name that was there but "first_name". Everything makes sense again now. Thanks guys and I really want to apologize for mixing things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Ruby 1.9 this is a bit more concise way to do it.

```
column_names = { 
  :first_name => "Student's First Name",
  :last_name  => "Student's Last Name",
  :email      => "Student's Email",
  :given_name => "Student's Given Name"
}

params = {
  :first_name => 'FirstName',
  :last_name  => 'LastName',
  :email      => 'Email',
  :given_name => 'GivenName'
}
col_titles = []

col_titles = column_names.values
data = params.values_at(*column_names.keys)

col_titles # => ["Student's First Name", "Student's Last Name", "Student's Email", "Student's Given Name"]
data # => ["FirstName", "LastName", "Email", "GivenName"]
```

This takes advantage of Ruby 1.9's new Hash behavior, where Ruby remembers the order of insertion and will honor that order when retrieving the keys and values. You can do something similar with 1.8, but you'd have to define the order of the columns in an array, then use that to pull the column headings and values of the data instead of relying on `column_names` to set the order.

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip man. This looks way cleaner than before!